# Скроллинг и обрезание краев фона

Tags: html, css

Есть `background`, размер его `1200px`,
верстаем для минимального браузера `1024px`.
Идея такова:

1. Если более 1024, то бекграунд показывается полностью
2. Если браузер 1024, то бекграунд расположен по центру и края у него чуть-чуть обрезаны
3. Если браузер меньше 1024, то показываем скролинг и края так же обрезаны, но вот тут что то и не получается.

Бекграунд ведет как-то странно, появляется скролинг и если левая часть обрезается, то справа появляется белое растояние.

Код css

```
body {
background: #e1e1e1 url('bg.png') no-repeat top center;
}
#button {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1000px;
text-align:right;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Ну, код css видим, код html где?

    #button {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 1000px;

Ни фига себе кнопочка!!!

Comment: Я его не светил ибо он абсолютно никакой
<body><div id="button"><a href="#">link</a></div>
а нужна ширина 1000 для того что б потом выравнять тот же <a> по правой стороне, да еще и для того что б появлялся скрол

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А дело в том, что body уменьшается по ширине экрана и обрезает картинку. Чтобы все работало как надо, пропишите `body,html{min-width:1000px}` или что-то вроде того.

Comment: min-width самое оно) + margin: 0px auto; не помешает!

Comment: Что-то вроде того - это хак под IE. А вдруг нужен? =)

Comment: Спасибо, body,html{min-width:1000px} помогло